# jq map object key value to array of objects containing both

Tags: json, jq, flatten

I would like to put an object parent key inside the object itself and convert each key value pair to an array

Given:

```
{
  "field1": {
    "key1": 11,
    "key2": 10
  },
  "field2": {
    "key1": 11,
    "key2": 10
  }
}
```

Desired output

```
[
   {"name": "field1", "key1": 11, "key2": 10},
   {"name": "field2", "key1": 11, "key2": 10}
]
```

I know that `jq keys` would give me `["field1", "field2"]` and `jq '[.[]]'` would give

```
[
  { "key1": 11, "key2": 10 },
  { "key1": 11, "key2": 10 }
]
```

I cannot figure out a way to combine them, how should I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generate an object in `{"name": <key>}` form for each key, and merge that with the key's value.

```
to_entries | map({name: .key} + .value)
```

or:

```
[keys_unsorted[] as $k | {name: $k} + .[$k]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like below. Get the list of keys in the JSON using `keys[]` and add the new field `name` by indexing key on each object.

```
jq '[ keys[] as $k | { name: $k } + .[$k] ]'
```

If you want the ordering of keys maintained, use `keys_unsorted[]`.